# Tensorflow Lite - detect face parts

Tags: tensorflow, object-recognition

I'm looking for a way to detect parts of a face (like eyes, nose, lips) with Tensorflow Lite. So far, I haven't seen much info. Is there a way to actually retrieve coordinates that describe this kind of data?

Thanks

Comment: There are currently no converted models. You can convert an existing model from tensorflow or if you want a simple api consider mlkit https://firebase.google.com/docs/ml-kit/detect-faces#example_2_face_contour_detection